# Javascript not working on browser firefox android

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript code is not working in Firefox on Android, but it does work in Chrome on PC. What do I need to fix so it works in Firefox on Android?

Screenshots:

- [Chrome on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFWnu.png)
- [Firefox on Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyiV2.jpg)

Code:

```js
function sum() {
    var txtFirstNumberValue = document.getElementById('stock').value;
    var txtSecondNumberValue = document.getElementById('prodsebelumnya').value;
    var txtThridNumberValue = document.getElementById('jumlah').value;
    var txtFourNumberValue = document.getElementById('prod').value;
    var txtFiveNumberValue = document.getElementById('tolak').value;

    var result = parseInt(txtFirstNumberValue) + parseInt(txtSecondNumberValue);
    //var result2 = parseInt(txtThridNumberValue) - parseInt(txtFourNumberValue);
    //var result3 = parseInt(txtThridNumberValue) - parseInt(txtFiveNumberValue);
    var result4 = parseInt(txtThridNumberValue) - (parseInt(txtFourNumberValue) + parseInt(txtFiveNumberValue));

    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        document.getElementById('jumlah').value = result;
    }

    if (!isNaN(result4)) { //produksi + tolak
        document.getElementById('sisa_stock').value = result4;
    }
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped ">
    <tr>
        <th width="10%">Stok Awal</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="stok" id="stock" onkeyup="sum();" readonly required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="10%">Terima</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="terima" id="prodsebelumnya" onkeyup="sum();" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="10%">Jumlah</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="jumlah" id="jumlah" onkeyup="sum();" readonly /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="10%">Produksi</th>
        <td><input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="prod" class="prod" name="produksi" onkeyup="sum();" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="10%">Tolak</th>
        <td><input type="text" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id="tolak" class="tolak" name="tolak" onkeyup="sum();" required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th width="10%">Sisa Stok</th>
        <td><input type="text" id="sisa_stock" name="sisa_stok" readonly required /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th style="visibility:hidden;" width="10%">Produksi Diterima</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: there's nothing in the code you'e shown that would prevent this from running the same in chrome or firefox regardless of which platform desktop or mobile -

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFWnu.png] and [https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyiV2.jpg]

Comment: yes, those are the same meaningless images you put in the question - what of it? perhaps browsers in android don't trigger keyup/keypress events seeing as there is no keyboard

Comment: thats right because onkeyup for keboard pc is not for android keyboard, what's the solution bro?

Comment: use events that do exist in android

Comment: can you show example code for event in android bro?

Comment: sorry, I don't write web pages specifically for android so I've never had the issue, I usually use frameworks that do the hard lifting for me

Comment: Since you now know what the root cause is you could update your question so others immediately see what you're looking for.

Comment: Gave it clear, attractive language and formatting, and fixed snippet errors